# How to ignore excel compatibility verification when converting to an old format?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm using the COM library to save in C# a xlsx file into an Excel 8 format.

The weird thing going on here is a compatibility verification popup, pausing the savingAs process and pointing out to some compatibility issues. These are not important errors, and the process becomes user-dependent because of this popup. Since I want to do it automatically, do you know how to jump this step?

Comment: how i can double vote to you for each ans and reply.???u saved my day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved it using Workbook's application object.

```
wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = false;
```